# Publishing .NET 6.0 WPF app with LocalDB : cannot connect to database

Tags: c#, sql-server, publish, localdb

I've written an application for someone that uses a SQL Server LocalDB database that I wish to deploy now.

My solution consists of three projects: a data access library, a WPF UI project and an SQL Server database.

My connection string looks like this:

```
"Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=DelsCRMDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
```

I've also played around with changing that to `AttachDbFileName=...` but that did not help either.

First I tried the Setup Wizard in Visual Studio. But that doesn't even create an .exe after installing the app. There are only dll and json files in the program folder. I added the primary output and content files from the main project and set the prerequisites so not sure what I'm doing wrong there.

Then I tried to create a setup routine with Advanced Installer and copy/pasted the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files from SQL Server Local DB > Instances folder in `Users/AppData`. I can install and start the application but it crashes as soon as it tries to access the database. I noticed in a lot of tutorials that the `.mdf` should be in the solution folder but this is not the case for me so I pulled them from SQL Server Management Studio.

I also tried publishing the project to a folder but the only reference to the database I can find in there is one .dll and one .pdb.

I'm really at a loss here as I have never deployed anything before. Any help is appreciated.

The following exception gets thrown when the programme tries to access the database.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.6.1.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Comment: So you want to install SQL Server along with your application? Personally, I wouldn't try. Local DB is really meant for development only. If you don't want to use a no-install, no-maintenance embedded database (SQLite) then I would just provide the user instructions on setting up the database server.

Comment: LocalDB is absolutely intended for shipping with applications.  It's just that the most popular application that ships LocalDB is Visual Studio.  But you're correct that many desktop applications don't really need SQL Server, and SQLite is simpler to deploy.

Comment: I haven't worked with SQLite so far and would prefer to get this to work with SQL Server.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I guess I misunderstood: [Microsoft SQL Server Express LocalDB is a feature of SQL Server Express targeted to developers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: That's confusing because it _was_ built to deploy with Visual Studio, but as-built it's the best package for redistributing SQL Server with _any_ desktop application.  You can redist regular SQL Server Express Edition, but the installer is larger, and it creates a Windows Servcie that runs all the time.

Answer (score 0):

> I can install and start the application but it crashes as soon as it tries to access the database.

So first, you need better error handling, at least displaying an error and/or logging before you allow the program to crash.

You must install LocalDB on the target machine.  The MSI is here: [Instructions to download the LoacalDB MSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15#installation-media).

And you should have a second machine, or [VM](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines/) to test your installation and setup, so you're not having to troubleshoot on someone else's machine.

Once you've got it working with manual setup, you can build an isntaller to automate the process.  See [WPF Deployment Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/deploying-a-wpf-application-wpf?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

When you Publish your .NET 6 WPF app to a Folder it should copy all the required DLL's into the same folder as your main .exe, eg

```
PS C:\Users\david\source\repos\WpfApp3\WpfApp3\bin\Release\net6.0-windows\publish> ls


    Directory: C:\Users\david\source\repos\WpfApp3\WpfApp3\bin\Release\net6.0-windows\publish


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        12/29/2021  11:37 AM                runtimes
-a----         4/17/2019   6:07 PM         260656 System.Data.SqlClient.dll
-a----        12/29/2021  11:37 AM           7727 WpfApp3.deps.json
-a----        12/29/2021  11:37 AM           6656 WpfApp3.dll
-a----        12/29/2021  11:37 AM         149504 WpfApp3.exe
-a----        12/29/2021  11:37 AM          13248 WpfApp3.pdb
-a----        12/29/2021  11:37 AM            372 WpfApp3.runtimeconfig.json
```

Or if you choose the self-contained option, .NET 6 for the target platform will be included in the publish output folder:

```
PS C:\Users\david\source\repos\WpfApp3\WpfApp3\bin\Release\net6.0-windows\publish> ls


    Directory: C:\Users\david\source\repos\WpfApp3\WpfApp3\bin\Release\net6.0-windows\publish


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        12/29/2021  11:37 AM                runtimes
d-----        12/29/2021  11:41 AM                win-x86
-a----         4/17/2019   6:07 PM         260656 System.Data.SqlClient.dll
-a----        12/29/2021  11:37 AM           7727 WpfApp3.deps.json
-a----        12/29/2021  11:37 AM           6656 WpfApp3.dll
-a----        12/29/2021  11:37 AM         149504 WpfApp3.exe
-a----        12/29/2021  11:37 AM          13248 WpfApp3.pdb
-a----        12/29/2021  11:37 AM            372 WpfApp3.runtimeconfig.json
```

Comment: I've installed and started the programme on two machines, one of them my own. Both have LocalDB installed of course. This is the exception that is thrown when the database gets accessed: 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.6.1.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Comment: See updated answer.